# What is the term for inserting that *may* lead to subsequent removal?

Tags: single-word-requests

In terms of any sort of collection of things, where the collection is limited in the amount of members it may have.  I suppose 'replacement' would be enough to describe insertion of one thing then subsequent removal of something else.

I am looking for, though, a term that describes insertion that **may** result in subsequent removal, but not necessarily.

Comment: I think side-effects are not usually described on the action. *Insertion* is the action. The side-effect is described by the name of the type of collection: *limited-capacity collection*.

Comment: The opposite of Jenga.

Comment: *Suggestion*? If I suggest an alternative or propose an alternative solution, I'm putting forward one thing that may or may not replace the existing thing.

Comment: If the same item would be removed then it would be "tentative insertion".

Answer (score 1):

If things are meant for future replacement:

•Ad Interim
•Provisionally

Or if it is intended human beings:

• Probationally.

Answer (score 0):

To **store** something somewhere means there is usually intent to retrieve it at some point, but it's not guaranteed. (Could forget about it, for example)